# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException' CoreData could not fulfill a fault for

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Things were working fine with my app until I PULLED the latest release. Now when I run my app I get the error mentioned above. There happens in the RKManagedObjectRequestOperations  saveContextToPersistentStore method.

Below is the code where I create an object, but near the bottom if I comment out one line the error never happens.  The code hasn't changed, I just updated RestKit from Github?  Any suggestions?

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

    User *joeBlow  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context ];

        joeBlow.username = @"jjjj";

        joeBlow.email = @"jason3@atsdfatsd.com";

        joeBlow.gender = @"male";

        joeBlow.password = @"12345";

        NSError *error = nil;

        [context save:&error];  <------- If I comment this code out the error goes away.

    [self.restEngine signUpNewUser:joeBlow];
```

**UPDATE**

If change the save to the following it works.

```
[[objectManager.managedObjectStore persistentStoreManagedObjectContext] save:&error ];
```

Does anyone know if using the following is no longer allowed in Restkit?

```
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
```